# How to extact very narrow water linear features from GeoEye-1 image

Tags: remote-sensing, digital-image-processing, feature-extraction, land-classification, geoeye

I need to extract beaver channels from a GeoEye image (attached image). What is the best approach to automatically delineate such very narrow and not very sharp water features?[image]

Comment: Very broad question, but have you tried edge-detection filters?

Comment: I am not very familiar with edge detection. Which filters to use? Can I find them in such programs like Arcgis, Erdas or ENVI?

Comment: ENVI has some tools. Try the Sobel Edge Detection in the Filter -> Convolutions and Morphology tool. See http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/DetectEdges.html for more info.